# Flask-SQLAlchemy Queue Pool limit reached

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy

I have an application where a service makes a POST request to a flask app which then inserts the body of request into a postgresql database into a table as well as inserting data into several other tables.
The problem occurs once a curtain amount of  requests are made that the queue pool limit is reach and the app throws an error.  i have isolated it down to the extra functions called to do the inserting into other tables. i don't understand what is happening.
Each service is a docker container

```
172.30.0.17 - - [16/Jun/2022 06:25:07] "GET /api/orgs HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2095, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2080, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2077, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1525, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1523, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1509, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/service/routes/get/get_org.py", line 17, in base_route
    query = [convert_class(item) for item in Organization.query.all()]
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2768, in all
    return self._iter().all()
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2903, in _iter
    result = self.session.execute(
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1711, in execute
    conn = self._connection_for_bind(bind)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1552, in _connection_for_bind
    return self._transaction._connection_for_bind(
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 747, in _connection_for_bind
    conn = bind.connect()
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3234, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self, close_with_result=close_with_result)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 96, in __init__
    else engine.raw_connection()
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3313, in raw_connection
    return self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, _connection)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3280, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 310, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 868, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 476, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 134, in _do_get
    raise exc.TimeoutError(
sqlalchemy.exc.TimeoutError: QueuePool limit of size 20 overflow 20 reached, connection timed out, timeout 30.00 (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/3o7r)
```

Config

```py
class Config:

    # Database
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = environ.get("DB_URI")
    SQLALCHEMY_ECHO = False
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
    SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS = {
        "pool_size": 1,
    "max_overflow": 0,
    }
```

App init

```py
db = SQLAlchemy()
# create flask App
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)

    # DB config - postgreSQL
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = getenv("DB_URI")
    app.config.from_object('config.Config')

    # config server with CORS
    # cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})
    

    with app.app_context():
        db.init_app(app)
        from service.routes.post import post_event

        return app


app = create_app()
```

POST request

```py
@app.route('/api/orgs/<org_id>/sites/<site_id>/sessions/<session_id>/events', methods=["POST"])
def edger_post_request(org_id, site_id, session_id):
    print("URL params: {}, {}, {}".format(
        org_id, site_id, session_id
    ))

    # parse body of post request
    try:
        request_body = request.json
        event_data = json.loads(request_body["data"])
    except:
        return "error in body of request", 400
        
    print("Body of request: ", request_body)

    # check if body of request is valid
    errors_body, has_error = validate_input(request_body)
    print(errors_body, has_error)
    if has_error:
        return Response(errors_body, 400)

    # insert event
    event_dict = dict()
    try:
        event_dict = {
        "id": request_body["id"],
        "timestamp": request_body["timestamp"],
        "type": request_body["type"],
        "event_type": event_data["type"],
        "data": request_body["data"],
        "org_id": org_id,
        "site_id": site_id,
        "device_id": request_body["device_id"],
        "session_id": request_body["session_id"]
        }
        
        if "frame_url" in request_body.keys():
            event_dict["frame_url"] = request_body["frame_url"]
        else:
            event_dict["frame_url"] = None




        insert_event = Event(**event_dict)
        db.session.add(insert_event)
        # commit event to DB
        db.session.commit()

        # Insert extra tables
        insert_threads(org_id, site_id, event_dict, event_data)
        db.session.commit()
        db.session.close()
        return {"result": "success"}, 200
    except Exception as e:
        print("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -")
        db.session.rollback()
        print("Error inserting Event", e)
        print("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -")
        db.session.close()
        return {"result": "unsuccessful"}, 409
```

insert_threads function

```py
def insert_threads(org_id, site_id, body, data):
    event_data_insert(body, data),
    event_type_insert(data["type"]),
    insert_org(org_id),
    insert_site(org_id, site_id),
    insert_device(org_id, site_id, body['device_id']),
    insert_session(org_id, site_id, body['device_id'], body['session_id'], body['timestamp'])
   
def insert_org(org_id):
    org_list = getattr(g, "org_list", None)
    # query organization insert if doesn't exist
    if org_list is None:
        check = [org.id for org in Organization.query.all()]
        g.org_list = check
        org_list = check
    if org_id not in org_list:
        insert_org = Organization(id=org_id, name="temp_name")
        db.session.add(insert_org)
        org_list.append(insert_org.id)
        g.org_list = org_list

def insert_site(org_id, site_id):
    site_list = getattr(g, "site_list", None)

    # query Site insert if doesn't exist
    if site_list is None:
        check = [site.id for site in Site.query.all()]
        g.site_list = check
        site_list = check
    if site_id not in site_list:
        insert_site = Site(id=site_id, org_id=org_id, name="temp_name")
        db.session.add(insert_site)
        site_list.append(insert_site.id)
        g.site_list = site_list


def insert_device(org_id, site_id, device_id):
    device_list = getattr(g, "device_list", None)
    # query device insert if doesn't exist
    if device_list is None:
        check = [device.id for device in Device.query.all()]
        g.device_list = check
        device_list = check
    if device_id not in device_list:
        insert_device = Device(id=device_id, site_id=site_id, org_id=org_id)
        db.session.add(insert_device)
        device_list.append(insert_device.id)
        g.device_list = device_list

    



def insert_session(org_id, site_id, device_id, session_id, timestamp):
    session_list = getattr(g, "session_list", None)
    # query session and insert if it doesn't already exist
    if session_list is None:
        check = [session.id for session in Session.query.all()]
        g.session_list = check
        session_list = check
    if session_id not in session_list:
        insert_session = Session(
        id=session_id,
        timestamp=timestamp,
        org_id=org_id,
        site_id=site_id, 
        device_id=device_id 
        )
        db.session.add(insert_session)
        session_list.append(insert_session.id)
        g.session_list = session_list

def event_data_insert(event, event_data):
    # get white list from global var else None
    query_list = getattr(g, "query_list", None)
        # if query_list is None get query_list from DB
    if query_list is None:
        check = [convert_class(item) for item in Event_data_query_list.query.all()]
        g.query_list = check
        query_list = check

    # loop though query_list and insert key/value pair into event_data table
    for key in query_list:
        print("the key: ", key)


        key_path = key["key_name"].split(".")
        # check if keys exist in data Object and continue down levels till the value is reached
        if key_path[0] in event_data["data"] and key["type"] == event_data["type"]:
            print("inside first if")
            value = event_data['data']
            for sub_key in key_path:
                print("inside loop")
                if sub_key in value.keys():
                    print("in subkey" , sub_key)
                    value = value[sub_key]

                # handle if keys and values dont exist
                else:
                    value = None
                    break
            if value is None:
                continue

            # determine where value is an Integer or a String and insert into correct column
            val_int = None
            val_str = None
            if type(value) == str:
                val_str = value
            elif type(value) == int:
                val_int = value

            # add event_data row to session
            insert = Event_data(event_id=event["id"], type=event_data["type"], key=key["key_name"], value_int=val_int, value_str=val_str )
            print("insert object", insert)
            db.session.add(insert)
    
def event_type_insert(event_type):
    event_type_list = getattr(g, "event_type_list", None)
    if event_type_list is None:
        check = [item.event_type for item in Event_type.query.all()]
        g.event_type_list = check
        event_type_list = check
    if event_type not in event_type_list:
        insert = Event_type(event_type=event_type)
        db.session.add(insert)
        g.event_type_list.append(event_type)
```

Comment: For clarity: `insert_threads` and the functions it calls do not create any actual [threads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html), is that right?  I ask because Flask-SQLAlchemy by default will automatically remove sessions at the end of each request, but sessions created outside of a request's thread will not be automatically removed.

Comment: No it doesn't create any threads its just a bad name